# Servlet 2.5 Automatic imports

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, weblogic

This is a strange which I'm hoping someone can shed some light on.  We are in the process of moving from Weblogic 8.1 to 10.3.4 and as part of this we are updating various things including our deployment descriptors.  In our webapp our web.xml was Servlet verion 2.3 with the following `<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN" "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">`

We have now changed it to 2.5 as follows `<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">`

Since the change we have come across some jsps that fail to compile at runtime. They fail because we haven't imported some necessary classes for that jsp. For example in one we are using a Calendar (java.util) but for whatever reason failed to write the import declaration for it. For some reason in 2.3 this didn't seem to matter. Does anyone know if this was a feature of 2.3 that certain classes were imported on the fly when the import was not declared. I fully appreciate they should be imported properly but I fear we may have a few other jsps which will fail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/webapp/weblogic_xml.html

> Implicit Servlet 2.5 Package Imports

The Servlet 2.5 specification mandates that only the java.lang.*, javax.servlet.*, javax.servlet.jsp.*, and javax.servlet.http.* packages be implicitly imported. In compliance with the Servlet 2.5 specification, WebLogic Server will only import these mandated packages. Whereas, previous releases of WebLogic Server also imported the java.io.*, java.util.*, and javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.* packages.

WebLogic Server will follow the previous 2.4 or earlier behavior and import the non-mandated packages, if any of the following occur:

The backward-compatible flag is set to true in the weblogic.xml descriptor file.

The web application version is 2.4 or earlier.

The individual JSP/TAG files in a version 2.5 web application are version 2.0 or earlier.

Comment: Now that's called answering a question!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the previous version of WebLogic did the import because it used Calendar (or java.util.*) internally. This is however not in the spec.

You could use the weblogic appc compiler (or jspc, but it's deprecated) to precompile the JSPs and see which ones don't compile.

See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/webapp/reference.html#wp57794

Comment: Thanks will do that and add the imports correctly. Can't be weblogic as the old web.xml was being used on weblogic 10.3.4 and worked and then we updated it to 2.5 and it stopped working.  Sorry should have made that clear.